# Highcharts: Click to update column color --- need a mouseover?

Tags: highcharts

I tried to plot a chart with column type with one series. The data can be both positive and negative. I tried to update the color of points that are larger than 0 (or less than 0) with one click. With the following example:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        for (var i = 0; i < this.series.data.length; i++) {
                            if (this.y < 0) {
                                if (this.series.data[i].y < 0) 
                                    this.series.data[i].update({ color: '#ECB631' }, false, false);
                            }else {
                                 if (this.series.data[i].y > 0) 
                                    this.series.data[i].update({ color: '#ECB631' }, false, false);


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, -71.5, 106.4, -129.2, 144.0, 176.0, -135.6, 148.5, -216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        negativeColor: '#FF0000'
    }]
});
```

Here is [the link](http://jsfiddle.net/CkkbF/57/). http://jsfiddle.net/CkkbF/57/

I found that something interesting and weird:

1. If the point data is positive, the clicked column color will be changed, but other columns with positive data have slightly different color (seem highlighted.)
2. If the point data is negative, the clicked column color will stay the same (red in my example) until you mouse out of it. The other columns with negative data stays the same unless you try to mouse in/out of them.

Possibly a bug? How can I update them correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to update series color, or series negativeColor, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/CkkbF/60/

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        if (this.y > 0) {
                            this.series.update({
                                color: "#ECB631"
                            });
                        } else {
                            this.series.update({
                                negativeColor: "#ECB631"
                            });
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! It seems that it cannot apply to more generic ones? I actually have a more complicated case, where each point has an id, if I click the column, all the columns with the same id will be changed to a particular color (no matter it is negative or positive). I abandoned the negativeColor idea, instead I iteratively color all the column when the chart is loaded. I know it's stupid, but it worked...

Comment: Looks like Highcharts have some issues with negative color